# spring data inheritance for repository reuse

Tags: java, spring-data

I am using Spring Data to load an object and all works well...However, I don't want to load the entire object as I am returning a list to display in a table, so I only want to load what is in the table.  then, when a user selects "details" I want to make an AJAX call to the server to load the entire object.  My thought was to have a Base Class "TableView" then to have a subclass "Class DetailsView extends TableView".  I could probably create a new repository, so one for the TableView and one for the DetailsView, but I'm wondering if there is a way to use the same repository class?  below is an example of what I'd like to do, but I'm not sure how to change the repositoryClass to achieve what I want...I get the following error:

SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet at  org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)

```
class TableView{
    String title;
}
class DetailsView extends TableView{
    String details;
}
interface ITableViewRepository extends CrudRepository<TableView, Integer>{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write two queries in your `TableViewRepository`.

One for returning `id` and `title` from you object

```
@Query("SELECT tv.id, tv.title FROM TableView tv") 
TableView findWithTitles();
```

And after that just call a method `findOne` with `TableView` `id` to return entire object.